# div content squeezed when I resize the windows

Tags: html, css

for some reason I don't specify its width, so it's relative, how to not to let the div resize when the windows is resizing? I tried overflow:hidden on the div but it does not work

Comment: Please post your code and more details about your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `overflow`:

```
.yourdiv {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

add a minimum height if that helps.

```
.yourdiv {
   overflow:hidden;
   min-height: 200px;
}
```

You can do the same thing with the width if needed.